Can massless W boson decay into two fermions?
Recently, I'm trying to evaluate the scattering rate above the EW scale(Before spontaneous symmetry breaking -> SM particles have zero mass).
About related calculation, below question make me struggled.
"Can massless W boson decay into two fermions?"
Naively, because of the properties of SU(2)_L, transverse mode of W cannot decay into two fermions.
Additionally, longitudinal mode is prohibited because W boson is massless.
Thus, I think the only one possibility is W boson acquire the plasmon(thermal) mass.
So, my question is

Can massless W boson decay into two fermions?
Is there any other mistakes/missing points about my idea?

Thanks about your answer.

Correct me if I am wrong, but a massless boson should not be able to decay into two fermions already on the kinematics level as it is impossible to satisfy 4-momentum conservation in this process.

That’s correct. A particle with zero mass cannot decay kinematically, and thus, to allow decays above the EW scale, particles must acquire a thermal mass. This was not clearly explained in the main text. To be precise, I'm considering the process where the W boson propagator decays into two fermions during the scattering process. I think this process should be possible regardless of the thermal mass. I apologize for causing any confusion.
